# Echo Result of MySQL SELECT Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, inner-join

I have page where I want to display a single value from one table based on a value found in another:

```
$username = 'Joe';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM chars WHERE uname = "$username"';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$query = 'SELECT cname FROM chars INNER JOIN usrs 
    ON chars.cid = usrs.clastused WHERE usrs.uname = "$username"';
$q = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
echo '<p>q = "'.$q.'" and r = "'.$r['cname'].'"</p>'; //for debugging
foreach ($row['cname' as $opt) {
    $output .= '<option value=\"'.$opt.'\"';
    if ($opt=$r) {$output .= ' selected';}
    $output .= '>'.$opt.'</option>';
}
```

PHPMyAdmin gives the response I expect **CNAME Joe** and `$q` gives **Resource id#5** but `$r` is blank.
How do I echo the result?
What I want at the end of the day is to have a dropdown list where the *clastused* is the preselected option.

Comment: so, you queried one field `SELECT cname FROM` but trying to echo another one `$r['charname']` ? try to add another one to the query, or to echo the same one `cname` as requested

Comment: Sorry @kim-alexander but this was a red-herring due to my mistyping. I have edited the code snippet to remove my error and add some context.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated. Consider using mysqli or PDO.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using the array variable directly:

```
foreach ($r as $opt) {
    $output .= '<option value=\"'.$opt.'\"';
    if ($opt=$cname) {$output .= ' selected';}  
    $output .= '>'.$opt.'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Result from dataBase are two dimensional:

```
result[0]['column1']
result[0]['column2']
result[0]['column3']
result[1]['column1']
result[1]['column2']
result[1]['column3']
```

So if your query returns 'cname'

you should:

```
echo $r[0]['cname']
```

Comment: Thanks @zafirov. I tried adding [0] to $r and it still returned a blank. I did not know about the two dimensional nature of the returned array and this titbit will help me out further along in my coding.

Answer (score 0):

You must try print_r instead of echo as its an array.
Try print_r($r);